# Does not contain a definition for 'AddComponent' and no accessible extension method 'AddComponent' error in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

In the code below, I'm trying to create an instantiate game object and have the component added to the expose to Editor but coming up to an error below in Unity.  It seems the _currentPiece can't be added to the ExposeToEditor and I'm trying to find a fix for it. What would be the workaround?

error CS1061: 'SnapPiece' does not contain a definition for 'AddComponent' and no accessible extension method 'AddComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'SnapPiece' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public class SnappableSpawner : MonoBehaviour
        {
            public GameObject prefabSnapPiece;
            public float initialDistanceToSpawnAt = 1f;
            private float _currentDistanceToPositionAt;

            private SnapPiece _currentPiece;
            private int _spawnSuffix = 1;

            public void SpawnGhostToMouse()
            {
                if( _currentPiece == null )
                {
                    _snapMode = PointerSnapMode.ABSOLUTE_PROJECTION;
                    _currentDistanceToPositionAt = initialDistanceToSpawnAt;
                    _currentPiece = GameObject.Instantiate( prefabSnapPiece ).GetComponent<SnapPiece>();
                    _currentPiece.name = "Spawned-"+_spawnSuffix;
                    _spawnSuffix++;

                    ExposeToEditor exposeToEditor = _currentPiece.AddComponent<ExposeToEditor>();
                    IRTE editor = IOC.Resolve<IRTE>();
                    editor.Undo.RegisterCreatedObjects(new[] { exposeToEditor }); 
            } 
       }
```

Comment: you probably want _currentPiece.gameObject.AddComponent... or such, you dont add monobehaviors to monobehaviors, but to gameobjects

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different to `GetComponent` which is implemented by both [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) and [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) (which MonoBehaviour inherits from)

the [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) is **only** implemented by `GameObject`.

You need to always go through the according `GameObject` like

```
ExposeToEditor exposeToEditor = _currentPiece.gameObject.AddComponent<ExposeToEditor>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification derHugo!  The code you have recommended has solved my coding error.